# Sobolev's inequality from Reed & Simon vol. II

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

In Reed & Simon vol. II, an inequality called *Sobolev's inequality* is stated in Eq. (IX.19):

> Let $0<\lambda<n$ and suppose that $f\in L^p(R^n)$, $h \in L^r(R^n)$ with $p^{-1} + r^{-1} + \lambda n^{-1} = 2$ and $1<p,r<\infty$. Then
>   $$ \iint \frac{|f(x)||h(y)|}{|x-y|^\lambda} d^n x d^n y \leq C_{p,r,\lambda,n}\|f\|_p\|h\|_r.$$

The proof is by an extension of Young's inequality using weak Lebesgue spaces.

My question is: is this inequality related to what is usually called "the Sobolev inequality", bounding $L^q$ norms in terms of $W^{p,k}$ (semi)norms?

Comment: It's a dual to the usual Sobolev inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually known as the Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequality. By the way, there is no Sobolev space, in the statement! See also [the classic paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2007032) by Elliot H. Lieb, *Sharp constants in the Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev and related inequalities*.

Most mathematicians call "Sobolev inequality" the main part of the Sobolev Embedding Theorem.

Comment: I have found that indeed the Sobolev embedding theorem and the Hardy--Littlewood--Sobolev inequality are related. According to [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#Hardy.E2.80.93Littlewood.E2.80.93Sobolev_lemma), Sobolev's original proof of the former involved the latter.